# Baseline Problem with zref & textblock (north west vs baseline)

Tags: baseline, zref

Zref does calculate the coordinate of north west of P1 (= baseline of "some text"), which in my case is approx (50mm, 274mm)

[image]

so if i make "uuuuuu" in Textblock with the same coordinates, it also puts "uuuuu" in north west. Then the baseline is not the same. The result seems like it shiftet.

**My simple question:** how can i force zref and textblock operate with the baseline and not north west?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,german]{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210 mm,paperheight=297 mm,left=50mm,top=20mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} 
\usepackage{zref-abspos}  
\usepackage{tcolorbox}  
%\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}


\topskip=0pt  
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % = global \noindent 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3} 

\newcommand{\myfunction}[1]{%
\zsavepos{P1}% Store the current position as #1
#1%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\dimtomm[1]{%
\strip@pt\dimexpr 0.351459804\dimexpr#1\relax\relax 
}
\makeatother

\textblockorigin{0mm}{297mm}
\begin{document}
some text

\myfunction{P1} 

\vspace*{5mm}
The coordinate of P1 is: (\dimtomm{\the\dimexpr \zposx{P1}sp \relax} mm,\dimtomm{\the\dimexpr \zposy{P1}sp \relax} mm)

\begin{textblock*}{\the\textwidth}(49.9994mm,-274.40306mm)%
    \textcolor{red}{uuuuuuu}
\end{textblock*} 

 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `\noindent` before `\zsavepos{P1}` inside the definition of `\myfunction` so as to save the position `P1` *after* starting a new paragraph (which was done by `\myfunction`'s first argument in your code, and caused the saved position to be above the baseline of the typeset text corresponding to `#1`).

I also added `[0,1]` after `\begin{textblock*}{\the\textwidth}` in order to vertically shift the block continaing `uuuuuuu` by its height (otherwise, its *upper* left corner would be at `P1`'s baseline, not its lower left one).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperwidth=210 mm,paperheight=297 mm,left=50mm,top=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}

\topskip=0pt
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % = global \noindent
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}

\newcommand{\myfunction}[1]{%
  \noindent\zsavepos{P1}% Store the current position as #1
  #1%
}

\textblockorigin{0mm}{297mm}

\begin{document}
some text

\myfunction{P1}

\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}[0,1](\zposx{P1}sp,-\zposy{P1}sp)%
  \textcolor{red}{uuuuuuu}
\end{textblock*}

% With multiline text
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}[0,1](\zposx{P1}sp,-\zposy{P1}sp)%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \color{blue}... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
  ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
  \end{minipage}
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also got it few minutes ago :) 
The last thing is to put around uuuuu a parbox as follows:
\parbox[t]{\the\textwidth}{\textcolor{red}{uuuuuuu}}
Then the text "uuuuu" starts above the baseline! Maybe u can edit it. Also u can put [0,1], [0,0], [1,1], [1,0] (or in between) to textblock, so that the alignment changes. U can put e.g. [0,1] as {\the\textwidth}[0,1](\zposx{P1}sp,-\zposy{P1}sp)

Comment: Ah, I had not quite understood what you wanted to achieve the first time. I added a `[0,1]` after `\begin{textblock*}{\the\textwidth}`; I believe this is what you want.

Comment: perfect! But if "uuuu" is more then 1 line, then it gets also shiftet. This is why i used parbox. Just try a long text instead of "uuuu" and u will see...

Comment: All right, I've added an example with multiline text using `\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth} ... \end{minipage}`.