# Height/vertical distance between baseline and descenderline: how to measure?

Tags: line, baseline

Do someone know, how to measure the space between the baseline and descender line?
And in general, is there a list with all those kind of measurements?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this depends on the design of the font, not on LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the contents in a `\hbox`. `\dp` will show the depth.

```
\def\showdepth#1{%
    \setbox0\hbox{#1}
    \edef\temp{\the\dp0}
    \leavevmode
    \box0:~
    \temp}

\showdepth g, \showdepth{$\displaystyle\int$}

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Can u help me with zref if you have experience in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582439/baseline-problem-with-zref-textblock-north-west-vs-baseline

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with `\zref`.

Comment: ok thanks!.....